# image not floating properly in chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, css-float

On this site> http://upcycledonline.com/test/Site/defaultUpCyc.html when I view it in chrome the rightEdge image looks like it is pushed down by something. I have rearranged the code several times and tried the image in different places with no luck. Help please!

Should I throw it in a div and try to make it do something that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the markup?  If so, do this:

```
<div id="header" style="overflow:auto">...</div>
<img src="leftEdge.png" style="float: left;">
<div style="float:left;">
    <img src="topEdge.png" style="float: left;">
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <img src="bottomEdge.png" style="float: left;">
</div>
<img src="rightEdge.png" style="float: left;">
```

Note that:

1. Nothing inside the new floated div should itself be floated.
2. You need that overflow:auto on the header
3. You will have to adjust the height of the content div

Comment: Thanks Law! I had to use a background image for the time being but will try this when I have to create the revamped site!